# Apple script open Terminal with ready command

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

I'm trying to open terminal using apple script with a ready command but without executing it and allowing user to do this just by clicking enter (so I don't want to use tell Terminal to do script)

One of the approaches I used is using keystrokes:

> tell application "Terminal"   do script "echo Hi!"
>   keystroke "abc" 
>   end tell

but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to start Terminal and have a command all lined up ready in the Terminal ready for the user so he/she only has to press "Enter". If so, you can do this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "echo hi"
    end tell
end tell
```

Then the user just has to press `Enter` and the command `echo hi` will execute.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I'm looking for. But it doesn't work for me. It opens the terminal but the command "echo hi" is not there.

Comment: I have added a delay to give Terminal a chance to start... please try again.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the way I ran it? I paste this script in script editor and than I run it. The terminal is launched but command "echo hi" is written at the end of the script in script editor and not in the terminal...

Comment: Try increasing the delay to 5, just to check if it's that.

Comment: I checked it. I made sure that Terminal is already up and running before calling keystroke command.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to understand what you mean.

You can't for instance have the terminal wait for a user to click its window.

(But you can poll for a keystroke after the terminal window is opened.)

You'd have to use a dialog before your code, in order to make the user enter the terminal consciously.

```
display dialog "Press ok to enter the terminal" buttons {"Cancel","Enter"} cancel button 1 default button 2
```

Other than that, the way you'd need to use system events to send keystroke to the Terminal

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell application  process "Terminal"
       keystroke "abcd"
   end tell
```

end tell

You can poll for a keypress in the do script command to your terminal with this:

```
read -n 1 -s MYCHAR </dev/tty
```

This will force the user to press enter from a do script

```
 a=`read`
```